# Excel - receiving run-time error 1004 ODBC Error

Tags: excel, vba

I am pretty unfamiliar with VB code and trying to solve an issue. Several users can run this macro fine, but some get a Run-time error 1004, General ODBC error. Debug points to the last line below. It is odd to me that it is setup to connect simply to a directory of a file share. Anyone know what may be going on? I have verified they have access to the share.

```html
  Option Explicit
  Sub CreatePolicyTable()
Dim qryTable As QueryTable
Dim rngDestination As Range
Dim strConnection As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strParam1 As String
Dim strParam3 As String

Worksheets("Pol Data").Range("A1:A1048576").EntireRow.ClearContents
Call Delete_Named_Ranges

'Define the connection string and destination range.
strConnection = "ODBC;Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};" & _
    "DBQ=\\My Folder\;" & _
    "Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;"
Set rngDestination = Sheet2.Range("A1")

'Create the SQL string.
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM My_File.csv"

'set the parameter strings
strParam1 = " WHERE state = '" & Sheet5.ComboBox1.Text & "'"
strParam3 = " ;"

'check & build variable parameters depending on whether combobox ticked by user
   strSQL = strSQL & strParam1 & strParam3

'Create the QueryTable.
Set qryTable = Sheet2.QueryTables.Add(strConnection, rngDestination)

'Populate the QueryTable.
qryTable.CommandText = strSQL
qryTable.CommandType = xlCmdSql
qryTable.BackgroundQuery = False
qryTable.Refresh

'Create Named Ranges
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="PolData", RefersToR1C1:= _
    "=OFFSET('Pol Data'!R1C1,0,0,COUNTA('Pol Data'!C1),COUNTA('Pol Data'!R1))"
End Sub

Sub Refresh_All()
Call CreatePolicyTable
Worksheets("Competitive Analysis").PivotTables("1").PivotCache.Refresh
Worksheets("Competitive Analysis").Activate
End Sub

Sub Delete_Named_Ranges()
Dim wbBook As Workbook
Dim nName As Name
Set wbBook = ActiveWorkbook
For Each nName In wbBook.Names
    nName.Delete
Next nName
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the code in `Delete_Named_Ranges`? You are also missing `End Sub` at the end of your sub, but that would give you a different error.

Comment: Thanks Pete, I edited the code to be more complete and easier to read.